# PHP(7) Dynamic session data retrieve

Tags: php, arrays

I read about session wrapping ways and there was method:

```
/*
    to set something like $_SESSION['key1']['key2']['key3']:
    $session->setMd(array('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), 'value')
*/
public function setMd($keyArray, $val)
{
    $arrStr = "['".implode("']['", $keyArray)."']";
    $_SESSION{$arrStr} = $val;
}
```

That's what I need but when I trying to use this way following:

```
$this->path = ['a','bb','ccc'];
$this->_sessionStorage{"['".implode("']['",$this->path)."']"} = 'dddd';
ddd($this->_sessionStorage);
```

I'm getting output like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["['a']['bb']['ccc']"]=>
  string(4) "dddd"
}
```

Is this fake or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is the expected behavior of php. If you want to access the data this way, you should use an loop. Something like this could work for you.

```
function setMd($keyArray, $value) {
    $data = &$_SESSION;
    foreach ($keyArray as $key) {
        $data = &$data[$key];
    }
    $data = $value;
}
```